# Find the number of 4 digit positive integers if the product of their digits is divisible by 3.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of 4 digit positive integers if the product of their digits is divisible by 3.

---

Let $abcd$ be the required number.For the product of digits of this number is to be divisible by 3,atleast one digit has to be 3,6 or 9.
Total there are 9000 four digit numbers.
The possible combinations are 3 and three other digits,33 and two other digits,333 and one other digit,3333,6 and three other digits,66 and two other digits,666 and one other digit,6666,9 and three other digits,99 and two other digits,999 and one other digit,9999.
I dont know how to solve further.

Comment: $0$ is also divisble by $3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many have a digit product that is **not** divisble by $3$? You can then only use $6$ digits for all digits as *also* $0$ is forbidden for all digits. In total, as you said, there are $9000  =9\times 10^3$ $4$-digit numbers..

Comment: Thanks,i understood.

Comment: @learner_avid Glad to be able to help. Counting the complement is a common technique.

Answer (score 1):

total numbers=9000.If a number has at least one of digit as 0,3,6,9 then the product can be divisible by 3.So left digits are 1,2,4,5,7,8 i.e 6 digits.total numbers by these 6 digits are 6^4=1296.
so total numbers divisible by 3 are:
9000-1296=7704.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).